# How to see which owner/contributor has deleted the Firestore data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

We are a team of developers working on an app for one and a half years, with the backend using `Firebase` and `Firestore` as `cloud database`. We have several owners and contributors to this project. Now our `Firestore` data and user authentication data have been deleted and we've lost almost everything. Is there a way to see which owner/contributor has deleted our data? And most importantly is there a way to retrieve this deleted data? Thanks in advance.

**Note: We are on the Blaze (paid) plan of `Firebase`.**

Comment: You should contact the support: https://firebase.google.com/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [audit logs for Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging) to log all operations on the database to Cloud Logging and Cloud Monitoring. That way you can see exactly what happened. You have to opt-in to this though, so this will only help you see who did what after you enable it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I mentioned we are on the blaze plan, and now we've lost all the CRUCIAL data of thousands of users. So is the recovery possible if we contact Google? Any suggestions from your side would be appreciated!!

Comment: Unless you've set up a [scheduled periodic export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) yourself, I don't think there's any backups to restore from. But it's anyway not something we can do much about here, so I recommend that you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to find out which collaborator on the project or which Authentication user deleted the data from Firestore.

If the data got deleted  accidentally from your database,as  Renaud Tarnec mentioned above in comment, you can reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) and ask for the data to be restored.

You can also check out [Announcing Automated Daily Backups for the Firebase Database](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/announcing-automated-daily-backups-for-the-firebase-database.html).